# How to send a string to a php file from Android?

Tags: java, php, android, sql

I have a php script on a local server that creates and manages an SQL table. I am able to create the table and database through my android app but I am having trouble figuring out how to send data to the php file. I want to send a string so that I can sort and pick the values to return to my app.

How do I change my php and android code so that I can get entries in the table between 2 dates?

Here is some of my Android code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.3/xampp/information.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
```

The beginning of information.php script is setup like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("data",$con);
```

How do I send a string from Android to the php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `$_POST` variables. So your `HttpPost` object would be initialized like this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.3/xampp/information.php?info="+nameValuePairs);
```

Then, in your PHP, just check to see if the variable `info` is set, and then process it if it is.

```
if(isset(_$POST['info']))
  //process data
```

This would, of course, requiring some formatting of `nameValuePairs` so that it is a valid URL, but it forces everything into one variable which you can easily check in your PHP.

Comment: It is easy but it may be create problem when the name valuepairs have ;arge number of data.At that time it gives the error like "Request-URI Too Large".